# Can you efficiently store many large documents in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have blobs of data that are large (greater than 500kB in size), but that will always be smaller than 1MB. I could store these blobs in something like Cloud Storage, but reading/writing them directly from Firestore would be much more convenient.

Firestore can hold documents up to 1MB in size, so my blobs will fit in Firestore documents, but the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) also states that:

> Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

This makes me think that reading and writing lots of documents near the 1MB limit will negatively affect Firestore's performance, slowing down access to other unrelated small documents. Is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of a document has no effect on the performance of queries in the Cloud.  What it will affect is the time it takes to transfer the contents of those documents to your client app.  Obviously, larger documents will take more time to transfer.  But the query itself is not going to take more time.

Firestore queries don't access the entire documents.  They use an index based on the contents of the fields that are required to satisfy the query.  Those indexes scale massively, and indexes are required to query data.  There are no "table scans" like SQL databases will do when there is no index to use.

The bottom line is this: don't worry about the size of a document for the purpose of query performance on the server. Worry about the size of a document for the purpose of its transmission to the client. If you want to better understand Firestore's known limits, I suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Answer (score 1):

> I have blobs of data that are large (greater than 500kB in size), but that will always be smaller than 1MB.

As long as your documents can stay below the 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes) limitation, you have nothing to worry about.

> Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

Any document size which is less than 1 MiB is considered a small document.

> This makes me think that reading and writing lots of documents near the 1MB limit will negatively affect Firestore's performance, slowing down access to other unrelated small documents.

The performance in Cloud Firestore depends on the number of items you're reading and **not** on the number of items in which you are searching. So if your query returns for example 5 items, it doesn't matter if the collection contains 10 items or 10 billion items, the time for getting those results will be the same. However, if the size of all your documents is almost 1 MiB then you should consider duplicating the data according to the queries you need to perform. For example, if you don't need the values of all the fields in a document and you only want to use three, then you should consider creating another collection that can hold the same documents but only with those three properties. In this way you'll not download documents with the size of 1 MiB, you'll only download documents with a size of 100 KiB perhaps, which is more convenient.

This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. If you are new to NoSQL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase Realtime Database but the same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that you need to keep in mind. In the same way, you are adding data, you need to maintain it. In other words, if you want to update/delete an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.